# How do I remove carriage returns with Ruby?

Tags: ruby, regex

I thought this code would work, but the regular expression doesn't ever match the \r\n. I have viewed the data I am reading in a hex editor and verified there really is a hex D and hex A pattern in the file.

I have also tried the regular expressions /\xD\xA/m and /\x0D\x0A/m but they also didn't match.

This is my code right now:

```
   lines2 = lines.gsub( /\r\n/m, "\n" )
   if ( lines == lines2 )
       print "still the same\n"
   else
       print "made the change\n"
   end
```

In addition to alternatives, it would be nice to know what I'm doing wrong (to facilitate some learning on my part).  :)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

What do you get when you do `puts lines`? That will give you a clue.

By default `File.open` opens the file in text mode, so your `\r\n` characters will be automatically converted to `\n`. Maybe that's the reason `lines` are always equal to `lines2`. To prevent Ruby from parsing the line ends use the `rb` mode:

```
C:\> copy con lala.txt
a
file
with
many
lines
^Z

C:\> irb
irb(main):001:0> text = File.open('lala.txt').read
=> "a\nfile\nwith\nmany\nlines\n"
irb(main):002:0> bin = File.open('lala.txt', 'rb').read
=> "a\r\nfile\r\nwith\r\nmany\r\nlines\r\n"
irb(main):003:0>
```

But from your question and code I see you simply need to open the file with the default modifier. You don't need any conversion and may use the shorter `File.read`.

Comment: There's an answer with more upvotes geared towards the "Strip newlines" further down: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7095275/403234

Answer (score 181):

Use [String#strip](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-strip)

> Returns a copy of str with leading and trailing whitespace removed.

e.g

```
"    hello    ".strip   #=> "hello"   
"\tgoodbye\r\n".strip   #=> "goodbye"
```

---

Using gsub

```
string = string.gsub(/\r/," ")
string = string.gsub(/\n/," ")
```

Comment: It won't filter newlines in the middle of text: 

    "line1\n line2".strip #=> "line1\n line2"

Comment: If used within a `each_line` call, then that doesnt matter.

Comment: Removing all surrounding whitespace != removing carriage returns

Answer (score 36):

Generally when I deal with stripping \r or \n, I'll look for both by doing something like

```
lines.gsub(/\r\n?/, "\n");
```

I've found that depending on how the data was saved (the OS used, editor used, Jupiter's relation to Io at the time) there may or may not be the newline after the carriage return. It does seem weird that you see both characters in hex mode. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 33):

If you are using Rails, there is a `squish` method

`"\tgoodbye\r\n".squish => "goodbye"`

`"\tgood    \t\r\nbye\r\n".squish => "good bye"`

Comment: For non-Rails users, it's implemented as `str.gsub(/[[:space:]]+/, ' ').strip`

Answer (score 18):

```
modified_string = string.gsub(/\s+/, ' ').strip
```

Comment: This replaces any whitespace character, not just CR/LFs

Answer (score 15):

```
lines2 = lines.split.join("\n")
```

Comment: This will also strip tabs and whitespace, which may not be what the user wants.

Answer (score 14):

`"still the same\n".chomp`
or
`"still the same\n".chomp!`

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-chomp

Comment: `chomp` will only removes from the end of a string, seems that the question wants to remove all carriage returns.

Answer (score 6):

How about the following?

```
irb(main):003:0> my_string = "Some text with a carriage return \r"
=> "Some text with a carriage return \r"
irb(main):004:0> my_string.gsub(/\r/,"")
=> "Some text with a carriage return "
irb(main):005:0>
```

Or...

```
irb(main):007:0> my_string = "Some text with a carriage return \r\n"
=> "Some text with a carriage return \r\n"
irb(main):008:0> my_string.gsub(/\r\n/,"\n")
=> "Some text with a carriage return \n"
irb(main):009:0>
```

Comment: also, I checked: "\r\n" != "\n".  So it looks like the original posters code is right.

Answer (score 5):

I think your regex is almost complete - here's what I would do:

```
lines2 = lines.gsub(/[\r\n]+/m, "\n")
```

In the above, I've put \r and \n into a class (that way it doesn't matter in which order they might appear) and added the "+" qualifier (so that "\r\n\r\n\r\n" would also match once, and the whole thing replaced with "\n")

Answer (score 4):

Just another variant:

```
lines.delete(" \n")
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not read the file in text mode, rather than binary mode?

Answer (score 2):

```
lines.map(&:strip).join(" ")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this :

```
my_string.strip.gsub(/\s+/, ' ')
```

Comment: Essentially the same answer as [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8891341/1735262) above.

Answer (score 0):

```
def dos2unix(input)
  input.each_byte.map { |c| c.chr unless c == 13 }.join
end

remove_all_the_carriage_returns = dos2unix(some_blob)
```