# Files Read and put it to in a loop with many to one relation Ruby

Tags: php, ruby, web-scraping, nokogiri, watir-webdriver

I am trying to assign a variable in watir method after reading the text file. I am using the following method. In loop, first loop is working fine but in second loop it shows error.

My code is as follows:

```
file = File.new("states.txt", "r")
contentsArray=[]  # start with an empty array
file.each_line {|line|
 contentsArray.push line
}

browser = Watir::Browser.new
browser.goto 'http://example.com'

for y in 0..2 do
puts state=contentsArray[y]
browser.text_field(:name => 'Keyword').set 'Pediatrics'
browser.text_field(:name => 'Address').set "#{state}"
browser.div(:id => 'uniform-formSearchDoctorBtn').fire_event :click

browser.link(:class => "start-over pull-right gen-button").click
 end
```

following error occurred .

```
`assert_exists': unable to locate element, using {:id=>"uniform-formSearchDoctorBtn", :tag_name=>"div"} (Watir::Exception::UnknownObjectException)
```

Where as when I am putting an static array in place of `contentsArray`

```
contentsArray=Array['AL','AK','AZ','AR']
```

Then code works fine.

Comment: The question is rather broad, which makes it difficult to answer. For example, are you having problems reading from a file or creating the different combinations? If you are having problems reading from a file, what type of file is it (ex Excel, csv, etc.). Please consider updating the question to show what you have tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: hi justin  i have edited the question .

Comment: If you output the `contentsArray`, you will likely get `["AL\n", "AK\n", "AZ\n", "AR"]`. Notice that there is a "\n", which is the line break character. You want to `strip` the line break by changing `contentsArray.push line` to `contentsArray.push line.strip`. For more details, see the question [How do I remove carriage returns with Ruby?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7095275/1200545)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes Got the solution with the help of justin.
if you output the contentsArray, you will likely get

```
["AL\n", "AK\n", "AZ\n", "AR"]
```

Notice that there is a "\n", which is the line break character. You want to strip the line break by changing contentsArray.push line to

```
contentsArray.push line.strip
```

For more details, see the question How do I remove carriage returns with Ruby? –  Justin Ko